# How to avoid leakage in the following FFT

Tags: fft

I have written code to perform the FFT of a signal which time domain plot and FFT is shown below.

I am not sure about what FFT length to use in order to avoid leakage of energy?

I know the number of periods has to be an integer, but I can't see how to implement this principle in here practically.

Also, I get an amplitude which is very far from 5 5 10 as written in the time domain signal.

Where did this go wrong?

[image]

[image]

```
    clc
    clear all
    Fs=200e3;
    Ts=1/Fs;
    dt=0:Ts:5e-3-Ts;
    
    f1=1e3;
    f2=20e3;
    f3=30e3;
    
    y=5*sin(2*pi*f1*dt)+5*sin(2*pi*f2*dt)+5*sin(2*pi*f1*dt)+10*sin(2*pi*f3*dt);
    %plot(dt,y)
    nfft=length(y);
    nfft2=2.^nextpow2(nfft);
    fy=fft(y,nfft2);
    f_half=fy(1:(nfft2/2));
    xfft=Fs.*(0:nfft2/2-1)/nfft2;
    plot(xfft,abs(f_half));
```

fixed final:

```
clc
clear all
Fs=200e3;
Ts=1/Fs;
dt=0:Ts:5e-3-Ts;

f1=1e3;
f2=20e3;
f3=30e3;

y=5*sin(2*pi*f1*dt)+5*sin(2*pi*f2*dt)+10*sin(2*pi*f3*dt);
%plot(dt,y)
nfft=length(y);
nfft2=1000;
fy=fft(y,nfft2);
f_half=2*fy(1:(nfft2/2));
xfft=Fs.*(0:(nfft2/2)-1)/nfft2;
plot(xfft,abs(f_half)/(nfft));
```

Updated FFT conv FIR

```
clc
clear all
Fs=200e3;
Ts=1/Fs;
dt=0:Ts:5e-3-Ts;

f1=1e3;
f2=20e3;
f3=30e3;

y=5*sin(2*pi*f1*dt)+5*sin(2*pi*f2*dt)+10*sin(2*pi*f3*dt);
%plot(dt,y)
nfft=length(y);
nfft2=1000;
fy=fft(y,nfft2);
f_half=2*fy(1:(nfft2/2));
xfft=Fs.*(0:(nfft2/2)-1)/nfft2;
%plot(xfft,abs(f_half)/(nfft));

cut_off=25e3/(Fs/2);
order=64;
h=fir1(order,cut_off);
con=conv(y,h)
%plot(con)
fz=fft(con,nfft2);
f_half_z=2*fz(1:(nfft2/2));
plot(xfft,abs(f_half_z)/(nfft));
```

Updated with filter response plot:

```
clc
clear all
Fs=200e3;
Ts=1/Fs;
dt=0:Ts:5e-3-Ts;

f1=1e3;
f2=20e3;
f3=30e3;

y=5*sin(2*pi*f1*dt)+5*sin(2*pi*f2*dt)+10*sin(2*pi*f3*dt);
%plot(dt,y)
nfft=length(y);
nfft2=1000;
fy=fft(y,nfft2);
f_half=2*fy(1:(nfft2/2));
xfft=Fs.*(0:(nfft2/2)-1)/nfft2;
%plot(xfft,abs(f_half)/(nfft));

cut_off=25e3/(Fs/2);
order=32;
h=fir1(order,cut_off);
fh=fft(h,nfft2);
plot(abs(fh(1:nfft/2)));
con=conv(y,h)
%plot(con)
fz=fft(con,nfft2);
f_half_z=2*fz(1:(nfft2/2));
%plot(xfft,abs(f_half_z)/(nfft));
```

new_update matching number of sample with the number of fft

```
clc
    clear all
    Fs=200e3;
    Ts=1/Fs;
    dt=0:Ts:(5e-3)-Ts;
    
    f1=1e3;
    f2=20e3;
    f3=30e3;
    
    y=5*sin(2*pi*f1*dt)+5*sin(2*pi*f2*dt)+10*sin(2*pi*f3*dt);
 
    nfft=length(y);
    fy=fft(y,nfft);
    %f_half=fy(1:(nfft/2));
    xfft=Fs.*(0:nfft-1)/nfft;
   
    plot(xfft,abs(fy)/nfft);
```

Comment: So, you know that the period of the signal needs to fit into the FFT length an integer amount of times. You know the period, right? So, where's the exact problem?

Comment: Hello Marcus,We have three signals in here  ,suppose i take the highest fd=30000 cycles/sec.

i am having problem with connecting the numbers in this terms.
the sinus period is 5 micro second,we sample our signal each 5e^-6 till 0.005 sec,so in total we have 1000 samples of the signal.
but we do fft on 1024 members ,so our frequency range(0-200Khz) is divided by 1024.
I have tried to implement the formula for leakage of the code i posted shown in the link bellow.
It doesnt give me whole integer number.
How do i choose the parameters for my 3 sinuses?
https://ibb.co/KqXNt1S
Thanks.

Comment: you realize that period is inverse to frequency, so your period is the least common mulitple of all the periods of the periodic components.

Comment: In case Marcus's hints are too subtle, or my answer doesn't manage to transmit the message: you have a 1000 points time sequence, on which you perform a 1024 points FFT, and which gives you spectral leakage due to the mismatch in the ratios. What can be done to match the ratio?

Comment: There are two answers to the question in the comment above: either match the number of samples to the FFT, or vice-versa. You did he first, I was aiming for the second, since you said you have to perform an FFT of 1024 points. so you could have just chosen `f1=1024, f2=20*f1, f3=30*f1`. Either way it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your frequencies `f2` and `f3` are a multiple of `f1=1k`, and since your time vector is until `5 ms`, that means your signal fits for a whole `5` periods, harmonics and all, so it's just ripe for a FFT. The problem you're having is that you chose the FFT to be of a number of points (`1024`) different than the number of samples (`1000`), so now one bin will be `Fs/nfft = 2e5/1024 = 195.31 Hz`. If you check the first values of the frequency vector `xfft(1:10)`, you'll see that the first frequency falls in between two bins:

```
            0
   1.9531e+02
   3.9062e+02
   5.8594e+02
   7.8125e+02
   9.7656e+02 % f1 is between this
   1.1719e+03 % ...and this
   1.3672e+03
   1.5625e+03
   1.7578e+03
```

The other two have the same symptom. This means the amplitude (which is not normalized, that's why it's `~5k`) can't be the real one. When the equivalent DFT will calculate the butterflies, the indices will not match `f1` at the same spot. If you would have performed the FFT for `1000` points, the bins would have been `2e5/1e3 = 200 Hz` in width. That would have made the frequency vector display these frst 10 values:

```
      0
    200
    400
    600
    800
   1000 % spot on
   1200
   1400
   1600
   1800
```

Using a `1024` length FFT means now there are more than one butterfly with different values, and they all add up. Which means you have a mild case of spectral leakage, i.e. the frequency that should have been present in one bin, only, is spreading across its neighbours. Also see [the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage) article.

Comment: Hello,So if my basic common frequency is 1000Hz then i need my FFT to be of the length of the basic frequency 1000.
Fd=1000Hz Fs=200000Hz N=1000 ,So its 1000,000/200,000=5.
I have normalised the result by 1000 as shown in the plot link  and the text code bellow. i get 2.5, 2.5, 5 amp.
Oiler formula says sinus will be displayed by two harmonics. 
Why sinus 30Khz where presented in 30Khz and 170Khz by FFT using oiler formula?
Thanks.
photo link of oiler formula:
https://ibb.co/Mp4hJQV
photo link of spectrum plot:
https://ibb.co/ZNtspqC
Text code:
https://textuploader.com/18ivu

Comment: @rocko445 **Euler**'s formula has nothing to do with harmonics here. The reason you see two images of the same sine is related to mirroring due to the sampling.

Comment: Hello,then why we get half the amplitude in both of them?
but sinus is represented by two harmonics not one.
Why in the FFT it is represented with one and half the amplitude?Thanks.

Comment: @rocko445 Your normalization is off by a factor of 2 then. Try `2/Nfft`.

Comment: @rocko445 Your question has been answered. What you want is not part of it, so make a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @rocko445 What that means is you're not restricted to only one question. Continuing this discussion in the comments with subjects other than your OP means that all the content with all the answers will remain obscure for future searches. What if someone else will want to know the same things we're discussing in the comments? No search will reveal these. That's why, if you have other topics you'd like to know about, post a new question.

Comment: yes ,i will post new different question.Thank you very much